# Why has my site slowed down with windows7 and IIS7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

My previous computer was a windows xp desktop with IIS6.

Now I have a faster computer, windows7 with IIS7 but my website on localhost seems much slower.

What could the reason be?

Comment: we really need some more information to know where to start looking... my guess is that because iis7 is bigger, and windows 7 is bigger, that they're combining to use more resources than the previous combination did; what is the actual slowness compared to the old computer? 5%? 50%?

Comment: "slowed down" isn't a good enough description of the problem... slowing down how and when? What kind of web site is it, static or dynamic and what technology and what does the slow part do? Generally my Server 2003 with IIS ran slower than Server 2008 with IIS7 does - but the client may prioritize differently (like giving up more cycles to improve user response elsewhere).

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, there are lots of kinds of slow-down, so you may need to be more specific. But I have three guesses:

1) There is one very common kind of web app slow-down that users going from XP to 7 will experience. Windows 7 (and Windows Vista) install IPv6 by default. Firefox and Chrome each operate very slowly over IPv6 in certain situations on Windows. If you are experiencing slowdown with Firefox (pages take forever to load, and images pop in really slowly), but not with IE, look into disabling Firefox's IPv6 support. This sped up my web apps in Firefox GREATLY!

2) I noticed that when I moved from XP to Windows 7 that my web applications started taking a LONG time to start (as long as 20 seconds, while those same web apps started in 4 or fewer seconds on the same hardware with Windows XP x64 and IIS 6)! They were very responsive after startup, however. There could be a million reasons for this, and I never figured it out. I still have the problem. But, I worked around it by using Visual Studio 2008's built-in web server, Cassini. Now I use Cassini to develop and only use IIS when I have to.

3) Nod32 v4 Anti-Virus on Windows 7 slowed down all my MySQL ODBC queries! It was fine on Vista and XP. I uninstalled Nod32 and the apps that use MySQL are fast again!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect it to be slower.  Could you have anything else in play like a database or web service call?  I would recommend testing a simple static page with a for loop (i.e. 1M iterations)  Compare the time.  Then start to bring more of your site back into the picture to see what is causing the differences.  IIS7 should perform as well or better in virtually very case.  Any chance you've moved to 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

How much slower are you talking about? It should be expected for your site to run a little slower, since you are running a newer operating system. XP was extremely stable and streamlined, while Windows 7 is just out and most likely unstable and slower. Of course if there is a significant slowdown something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, if correctly configured, Win7 on the same computer is unlikely to be noticeably slower. On a faster computer, there ought to be improved performance.

Answer (score -3):

W7 uses much more resources than XP. Running a local web server requires more power one should think, since You got several apps playing ping pong while sharing the same resources.

Comment: he does say it's a faster computer, though

Comment: -1, Windows 7 is way lighter on resources than you think. I have it running on an old Athlon XP 2600+ with 1GB RAM and I can't honestly say it's slower than XP on the same box.